# Quantifier Elimination in the quantifier free type

Tags: model-theory, quantifier-elimination

Show that if in the theory of $T$ every quantifier-free type has a unique extension to a complete type, then $T$ has quantifier elimination.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem? What have you tried?

Comment: Every quantifier free type? Also the type $p(x,y)=\{x=x,y=y\}$?

Comment: @PrimoPetri The statement is true when "quantifier free type" means "complete quantifier free type" (i.e., contains $\varphi$ or $\neg \varphi$ for all $\varphi$ quantifier free), as it does in some model theory writing.

Comment: Now it is clear. The claim can be rephrased as follows: if every complete type is equivalent to a quantifier-free type, then $T$ has elimination of quantifiers. I would add an explicit answer if some overzealous moderators had not put the question on hold.....

Answer (score 3):

**Hint for abstract proof approach:** continuous bijections between compact Hausdorff spaces are homeomorphisms, and the Stone Representation Theorem is true.

**Hint for concrete proof approach:** you're going to need to use the compactness theorem somewhere. Probably twice. Start by considering, for a formula $\varphi(x)$, the set of quantifier free formulas that $\varphi(x)$ implies.